# Sorting by date with null values not working JSON object.

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

Sorry I am new to javascript, but I am currently attempting to sort my JSON object according to attribute but right now it does not sort.

For example: I try to do this:

```
function sortByKey(array, key)
{

  return array.sort(function(a, b) {
  let x = a[key];
  let y = b[key];
  x = new Date(a.dateModified);
  y = new Date(b.dateModified);
  return x>y ? -1 : x<y ? 1 : 0;
});
}
```

And I try to sort according to "lastCompletedEvaldate" :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "<a MongoDB object ID>",
    "name": "Fred Flintstone",
    "email": "fflintstone@hotmail.com",
    "sex": "male",
    "tags": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ],
    "lastCompletedEvalDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.955",
    "pendingEvalSentDate": null,
    "pendingEvalViewedEmailDate": null,
    "pendingEvalClickedLinkDate": null

  },
  {
    "_id": "<a MongoDB object ID>",
    "name": "Barney Rubble",
    "email": "barney@gmail.com",
    "sex": "intersex",
    "tags": [],
    "lastCompletedEvalDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.954",
    "pendingEvalSentDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.955",
    "pendingEvalViewedEmailDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.955",
    "pendingEvalClickedLinkDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.955"

  },
  {
    "_id": "<a MongoDB object ID>",
    "name": "Bambam Rubble",
    "email": "bam@bam.com",
    "sex": null,
    "tags": [
      "baz"
    ],
    "lastCompletedEvalDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.955",
    "pendingEvalSentDate": null,
    "pendingEvalViewedEmailDate": null,
    "pendingEvalClickedLinkDate": null
  }
]
```

However, when I use the function like so:

```
let temp = sortByKey(file, 'lastCompletedEvalDate');
```

and output it using a get request:

```
router.get('/dash/participant', function(req, res){
  res.send(temp);
});
```

I still get the same output back not sorted. Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes.  You set x to `a[key]`.  key holds `"lastCompletedEvalDate"`.  `a.lastCompletedEvalDate` exists and looks like a date.  But then. you completely ignore that value and set `x` to a `Date` created from `a.dateModified` ... which does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you sort the array by `dateModified` ignoring `key`. Try following

```
function sortByKey(array, key)
{
  return array.sort((a, b) => 
    -(a[key] > b[key]) || +(a[key] < b[key])
  );
}
```

I replaced `new Date` with simple string comparison, see comments below.

Also, `Array.prototype.sort` does sort in place, so to keep the original array you probably want to clone it first:

```
let temp = [...file];
sortByKey(temp, 'lastCompletedEvalDate');
```

Comment: or for a simpler version: `return x.getTime() - y.getTime()`

Comment: @Tibrogargan yeah, but the shortest version, I believe, is 
`array.sort((a, b) =>  -(a[key] > b[key]) || +(a[key] < b[key]))`

Comment: `new Date("2018-05-14 12:02:14.955")` returns an invalid date in Safari (because the string is not consistent with the format defined in ECMA-262). There is no need to use Date objects at all, the dates can be sorted as strings.

Answer (score 2):

You should always avoid the built-in Date parser if there is any viable alternative (see [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)). In this case, the string "2018-05-14 12:02:14.955" is not consistent with the format in ECMA-262 so an implementation may return an invalid date (and Safari does).

Since the date strings will sort as strings, use *localeCompare* instead of creating Date objects:

```js
function sortByKey(array, key) {
  return array.sort((a,b) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]));
}

var data = [{
    "lastCompletedEvalDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.955",
    "pendingEvalSentDate": null,
  },
  {
    "lastCompletedEvalDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.954",
    "pendingEvalSentDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.955",
  },
  {
    "lastCompletedEvalDate": "2018-05-14 12:02:14.955",
    "pendingEvalSentDate": null,
  }
];

sortByKey(data, 'lastCompletedEvalDate');

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
function sortByKey(array, key)
{ 
   return array.sort((a, b) => 
      new Date(a[key]) - new Date(b[key])
   ) 
}
```

You can also check in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)